# How to join three table using sql, in zend framework

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have three tables named: employees, products, and bid.

employees table structure below

```
id | employee_id | isid | ename| email | password |admin |practice| phone
```

bid table structure

```
bid_id | product_id | employee_id | bid_amount | LastUpdate
```

product table structure

```
product_id |employee_id |name|type|brand|model |condition|about|verified|reserved_price
```

Now I want write a query to get all values from "products" and "bid_id" "bid_amount" from "bid" table.  Then, Employee name(ename) from "employees" table. How to write SQL query for that in Zend framework structure?
Previously I've written a query to take all "products" table values and corresponding "bid_id" and "bid_amount" values from the bid table. 
Now I want to display the corresponding employee name(ename).  So I need to join to "employees" table.
can anyone help me to do this?
My previous query for all "products" table values and "bid_id" "bid_amount" from bid table is below. It works perfectly.

```
 public function fetchAllProductItems() {
    $oSelect = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
            ->joinLeft(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
            ->group('p.product_id')
            ->having("p.verified = ?", "Yes");

    return $oSelect;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(['p' => 'products'],['*'])
    ->joinLeft(['b' => 'bid'],'b.product_id=p.product_id', ['bid_id','bid_amount'])
    ->joinInner(['e' => 'employees'], 'e.employee_id=b.employee_id',['ename'])
    ->where("p.verified = 'Yes'")
    ->group('p.product_id');
```

or

```
return $this->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(['b' => 'bid'],['bid_id','bid_amount'])
    ->joinInner(['p' => 'products'],'p.product_id=b.product_id',[
        'product_id',
        'product_name' => 'name',
        'product_type' => 'type',
        'product_brand' => 'brand',
        'product_model' => 'model',
        //etc
        ])
    ->joinInner(['e' => 'employees'],'e.employee_id=b.employee_id',[
        'employee_id',
        'employee_name' => 'ename'
        ])
    ->where("p.verified = 'Yes'");
```

Comment: when i used first one, its fetching only first value from products whose verified field is yes.